# Why does the awakened thread always preempt the lock first?

Tags: java

I have a problem with synchronized as follows.

```
public class Test {
    private final static Object LOCK = new Object();

    public void startThreadA() {
        new Thread(() -> {
            synchronized (LOCK) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": get lock");
                //start thread-B
                startThreadB();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": start wait");
                try {
                    //thead-A wait
                    LOCK.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": get lock after wait");
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": release lock");
            }
        }, "thread-A").start();
    }

    private void startThreadB() {
        new Thread(() -> {
            synchronized (LOCK) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": get lock");
                //start thread-C
                startThreadC();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": start notify");
                //notify thread-A
                LOCK.notify();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": release lock");
            }
        }, "thread-B").start();
    }

    private void startThreadC() {
        new Thread(() -> {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": thread c start");
            synchronized (LOCK) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": get lock");
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": release lock");
            }
        }, "thread-C").start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().startThreadA();
    }
}
```

When thread-B releases the lock, both thread A (Waken up by thread-B) and thread C (thread-B **startThreadC()**) are **blocked** trying to acquire the lock

I ran the following code many times in JDK 8 on Windows and Linux, The running results:

```
thread-A: get lock
thread-A: start wait
thread-B: get lock
thread-C: thread c start
thread-B: start notify
thread-B: release lock
thread-A: get lock after wait
thread-A: release lock
thread-C: get lock
thread-C: release lock
```

I think it is unfair that thread-A and thread-C both have a chance to preempt the lock. Why does thread-An always acquire the lock when thread-B releases the lock, What's the problem?